# Split SQL server string that has Decimal points into multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

```
Col
=========================
1270.8/847.2/254.16/106.9
```

And I would like to be split into columns like so:

```
Col1         Col2         Col3         Col4
============================================
1270.8       847.2        254.16       106.9
```

I have the code below, but it doesn't take the decimal into consideration.

```
Declare @Sample Table
(MachineName varchar(max))

Insert into @Sample
values      ('1270.8/847.2/254.16');

SELECT 
     Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(MachineName), '/', ''), 1)) As [M1]
   , Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(MachineName), '/', ''), 2)) As [M2]
   , Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(MachineName), '/', ''), 3)) As [M3]
FROM @Sample
```

Comment: Seems like somebody made a poor decision storing data like that... Will only cause lots of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()`.

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden and conditional aggregation:

```
declare @Sample Table (id int not null identity(1,1), MachineName varchar(max));
insert into @Sample values ('1270.8/847.2/254.16'),('1270.8/847.2/254.16/106.9');

select 
    t.id
  , m1 = max(case when s.ItemNumber = 1 then s.Item end)
  , m2 = max(case when s.ItemNumber = 2 then s.Item end)
  , m3 = max(case when s.ItemNumber = 3 then s.Item end)
  , m4 = max(case when s.ItemNumber = 4 then s.Item end)
from @Sample t
  cross apply dbo.delimitedsplit8K(MachineName,'/') s
group by id
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WJVLB77682

returns:

```
+----+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| id |   m1   |  m2   |   m3   |  m4   |
+----+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|  1 | 1270.8 | 847.2 | 254.16 | NULL  |
|  2 | 1270.8 | 847.2 | 254.16 | 106.9 |
+----+--------+-------+--------+-------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

Comment: I bet you have answer this question a few times ;)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza ^.^

Answer (score 2):

Everyone should have a good split/parse function as illustrated by SQLZim (+1), but another option could be as follow:

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Col varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'1270.8/847.2/254.16/106.9')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Col1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','float')
                      ,Col2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','float')
                      ,Col3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','float')
                      ,Col4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','float')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Col,'/','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

Returns

```
ID  Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
1   1270.8  847.2   254.16  106.9
```

> **EDIT - If 2012+, and just to be super-duper safe**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Col1 = try_convert(float,xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(100)'))
                      ,Col2 = try_convert(float,xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(100)'))
                      ,Col3 = try_convert(float,xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(100)'))
                      ,Col4 = try_convert(float,xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(100)'))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Col,'/','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

Comment: I prefer this, as it is 1) *ad-hoc-SQL* and 2) returns the values typed.

Comment: @Shnugo You may notice your piece making it XML save ... §§Split§§

Comment: Done well you have my Padavan. May the code be with you!

Comment: @Shnugo  Just trying to estimate where you land on the "Geek Scale"... When you typed that last message, did you just hear Yoda's voice in your head, or did you actually vocalize it ?

Comment: No, I must admit I'm more sort of a *Trekkie* :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016, you can use String_Split()

```
;with cte as (
select RowN = row_number() over(order by (SELECT NULL)), * from string_split('1270.8/847.2/254.16/106.9','/')
) select * from cte
pivot (max(value) for RowN in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) p
```

If you are using less than SQL Server 2016 version then you might require to use custom split functions... Many ways to write custom split function one easier way is to write using xml

```
CREATE Function dbo.udf_split( @str varchar(max), @delimiter as varchar(5) )
RETURNS @retTable Table 
( RowN int,
value varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml as xml
    SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@str,@delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)
    INSERT INTO @retTable
    SELECT RowN = Row_Number() over (order by (SELECT NULL)), N.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)') as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)
RETURN
END

--Your query

;with cte as (
select * from udf_split('1270.8/847.2/254.16/106.9','/')
) select * from cte
pivot (max(value) for RowN in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) p
```

But mine is similar to John's solution... Just now only looking at that

If you are using in value in a table then you can use cross apply as below

```
create table #t (v varchar(50), i int)
insert into #t (v, i) values ('1270.8/847.2/254.16/106.9',1)
,('847.222/254.33/106.44',2)

select * from #t t cross apply string_split(t.v, '/')
```

Comment: Question: What is the syntax for String_split if I need to input my column name? I never heard of this function before. Thanks!

Comment: You can do that using cross apply... Added similar examples at the end

Comment: Hi, Thank you. But the example above gives the output in separate rows, I want to have new columns for each value. I tweaked your script a little bit but it is not splitting the column

Comment: ;with cte as (
select RowN = row_number() over(order by (SELECT NULL)),*
from #TEST t cross apply string_split(t.Value, '/'))
select * from cte
 pivot (max(value) for RowN in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) p

Comment: Added another answer just by pivoting

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #t (v varchar(50), i int)
insert into #t (v, i) values ('1270.8/847.2/254.16/106.9',1)
,('847.222/254.33/106.44',2)

--Just to get all the values
select * from #t t cross apply string_split(t.v, '/')

--Inorder to get into same row -pivoting the data
select * from (
select * from #t t cross apply (select RowN=Row_Number() over (Order by (SELECT NULL)), value from string_split(t.v, '/') ) d) src
pivot (max(value) for src.RowN in([1],[2],[3],[4])) p
```